# Debugging a javascript error

Tags: javascript, debugging, internet-explorer-8

There is a script error on one of my web pages in IE8. Here's the screenshot of the error message -

[image]

I am trying to find what is causing this error. I have looked at the javascript files included and none of them have line 1174. However, there are minified versions of some files which have a few very long lines so I think the error could be there ?

How do I get this sorted? any ideas. thanks for your help.

**UPDATE**

I managed to solve the issue. It was the "buttons" option of the JQuery dialog. It had `class` without quotes around it and IE7/IE8 it was looking for `"class"`. All sorted now.

Comment: Open _IE10_, navigate to offending webpage, press `F12`, switch to the `Console` tab in the new panel, click on `Browser Mode` and select _IE8_. Then re-take steps to produce error and view the message there.

Comment: Use firebug to find out exact issue.

Comment: I tried F12 with Browser Mode IE8 but I didnt get error. When I test using IETester IE8 tab I get the above screenshot error.

Comment: I don't see any errors at all in Firebug.

Comment: Wild guess: Does your HTML have some inline script at the line in question?

Comment: Yes but not much. The total number of lines of HTML is 455. Checked by opening view source page.

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error you're seeing but I would recommend running the page through the W3 validator (http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdirectory.warwickshire.gov.uk%2Fsearch2.php%3Fkeywords%3Dhome&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Comment: Could I ask how did you test it? It only happens in IE8 (not in the Browser Mode of IE10 but when you test via IETester or IE8 itself)

Comment: Ok I now know where the error lies. It's do with the Jquery dialog as I was temporarily removing/hiding script for testing purposes and removing jquery dialog didn't show error. Still not sure why it is causing this error in IE8 only?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have a trailing semicolon at the end of an object, like so :

```
var foo = {
    bar: 1,
    baz: 2,
}
```

Unfortunalety IE8 has a strange way to count lines as it start counting in the HTML file and keeps on counting as it includes the javascripts.
So it is normal that the line shown does not exists.

I would use IE10 the pinpoint the exact location of the issue, as it does count more logically.

If you don't have access to IE10, search for the following regex in your files : ",[\n \t]*}". That should give you the semicolon you are searching for.

Comment: I understand what the issue is. but I don't know where that line is. None of the files has over 500 lines.

Comment: Have you tried IE10 ? Have you tried to do a regex search on your files with Notepad++ or a similar editor ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried in IE10 and switched browser mode to IE8. It dont get this error in IE10 (or IE8 Browser Mode). I only get this error when testing in IETester or IE8 version of IE.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue. It was the "buttons" option of the JQuery dialog. It had class without quotes around it and IE7/IE8 it was looking for "class". I added the quotes and it's all sorted now.